# Propiedades CSS no se aplican en grid layout

Tags: html, css, css3, css-grid-layout

estoy teniendo un problema con un grid que estoy intentando hacer, 
sucede que las propiedades CSS no se aplican al grid, cuando quiero colocarlos en determinada posición.
Tengo un div grid contenedor con clase "grid" y los elementos dentro son img con clases "1,2,3,4,5".
Cuando le aplico CSS a img se aplican perfecto pero al intentar mover las imagenes con su respectivo class, no se aplican los cambios.

Html:

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="1">
 <img src="https://www.elquintobeatle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/arctic-monkeys-favourite-worst-nightmare-1.jpg"> 
  </div>

  <div class="2">
  <img src="https://www.elquintobeatle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/arctic-monkeys-humbug-1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="3">
    <img src="https://www.elquintobeatle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/arctic-monkeys-suck-it-and-see-1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="4">
    <img src="https://www.elquintobeatle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/arctic-monkeys-am-1b.jpg">
    </div>

  <div class="5">
    <img src="https://www.elquintobeatle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/arctic-monkeys-tranquility-base-hotel-casino-1-1068x1068.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.grid{
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 32% 32% 32%;
  grid-template-rows: 32% 32%;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

img{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.1{
  grid-row:1/3;
}
```

No entiendo porque sucede esto, agradecería mucho la ayuda,  [les dejo el link de mi codepen.](https://codepen.io/florci1/pen/PoPXWyY?editors=1100)

Comment: Agrega aquí tu código por favor

Comment: @BetaM Ahi agregué el código, gracias por responder!

Comment: No se entiende tu duda, por favor explica mejor ¿cuál es el problema?